# Why is std::allocator a template?

Tags: c++

The job of an allocator is to obtain "raw" memory via its `allocate` method. What the caller constructs in the memory returned by the allocator is of no concern to the allocator (right?). So why is `std::allocator` a template when this only seems to add unnecessary complexity? What does the allocator actually do with that type information? Why  does it have to know the type of object the memory  is for? I'm assuming that there is some obvious reason that I'm missing, so what is that reason?

Comment: cppreference page got also section named : Concept,, You could check information about allocators there http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

Comment: you shouldn't have accepted the answer so fast, there could've been better answers/perspectives coming up...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `std::allocator`, and the Allocator concept itself, were invented to deal with issues like near- and far-pointers, or generally pointers to different address-spaces. And they deal with that ... adequately. The allocator determines the pointer-type used.

They can also be used to deal with different memory-allocators, though the amount of boilerplate for that is somewhat staggering.

And finally, an allocator-aware container can coupled with an allocator taking advantage of that provide a sub-allocator to child-elements, which might help reduce overhead.

---

The first point is nowadays mostly obsolete, though it can be used with the second point to have a mapping-address-invariant container in a shared memory segment, or a file.

The second point can be used for taking advantage of specialized allocators, though the interface is not really good for that. An example where I used it to [hack me a secure `std::basic_string`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107991/hacking-a-securestring-based-on-stdbasic-string-for-c).

And the last point is rarely used.

---

The one huge disadvantage of the Allocator concept as defined is the fact that it uses a template. All use already goes through `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>`, so it just leads to types inadvertently being almost the same, were there not the template-argument to the allocator.
And also to much duplicated code to rebind the allocator appropriately.

Comment: you can still have different address spaces, although it's platform dependant. Platform with different  addressing still exist. Also  allocator may be used with  placement new expression to allocate in pool

Comment: The first point is why we can use shared memory from C++. And btw, the secure allocator idea is surprisingly popular, check out mongodb, botan, bitcoin, or even jsoncpp

Answer (score 7):

Alignment comes to mind. Different types have different alignment requirements, a memory location that is good for a `char` array may not be good for a `double` (which generally require 8-byte aligned addresses).

OTOH, it should be noted that `malloc` solves this problem by providing memory that have a correct alignment for the most stringent of the built-in types, which is generally a good enough solution for a general-purpose allocator.

Comment: I don't find the argument convincing enough, if alignment is needed, the alignment itself should be the argument, ie `allocator<alignof(T)>`

Comment: @PasserBy: IIRC in C++03 there was no such a thing as `alignof`.

Comment: Fair point. `std::allocator` seems to be the product of a whole series of unfortunate events

Comment: @PasserBy Much like C++ itself. ;-)